# Example for using React Native's Stylesheet setStyleAttributePreprocessor method?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

We've noticed the StyleSheet has a [method](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/stylesheet.html#setstyleattributepreprocessor) called **setStyleAttributePreprocessor** which:

> Sets a function to use to pre-process a style property value. This is used internally to process color and transform values. You should not use this unless you really know what you are doing and have exhausted other options.

I wonder if there is an example of use. Basically we would like to scale width and height according to the screen's size all across the app:

```
const {
    width,
    height
} = Dimensions.get('window');

const widthScale = width / 320;
const heightScale = height / 568;
```

Answer (score 3):

Ended up doing this:

```
import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {Dimensions} from 'react-native';

const {
    width,
    height
} = Dimensions.get('window');

const widthScale = width / 320;
const heightScale = height / 568;

const widthRatioKeys = {
    fontSize: true,
    paddingHorizontal: true,
    paddingLeft: true,
    paddingRight: true,
    padding: true,
    marginHorizontal: true,
    marginRight: true,
    marginLeft: true,
    margin: true,
    borderRadius: true,
    borderWidth: true,
    right: true,
    left: true,
}

const heightRatioKeys = {
    paddingVertical: true,
    paddingTop: true,
    paddingBottom: true,
    marginVertical: true,
    marginTop: true,
    marginBottom: true,
    height: true,
    minHeight: true,
    lineHeight: true,
    top: true,
    bottom: true,
}


Object.keys(widthRatioKeys).forEach(key => {
    StyleSheet.setStyleAttributePreprocessor(key, (value) => {
        return value * widthScale;
    });
});

Object.keys(heightRatioKeys).forEach(key => {
    StyleSheet.setStyleAttributePreprocessor(key, (value) => {
        return value * heightScale;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer below implemantation:

```js
import {Dimensions, PixelRatio, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const {width, height} = Dimensions.get('window');

const PROPERTIES_DEPENDING_ON_WIDTH = [
  'width',
  'marginLeft',
  'marginRight',
  'marginHorizontal',
  'paddingLeft',
  'paddingRight',
  'paddingHorizontal',
  'borderLeftWidth',
  'borderRightWidth',
  'left',
  'right',
  'minWidth',
  'maxWidth',
];

const PROPERTIES_DEPENDING_ON_HEIGHT = [
  'height',
  'marginTop',
  'marginBottom',
  'marginVertical',
  'paddingTop',
  'paddingBottom',
  'paddingVertical',
  'borderTopWidth',
  'borderBottomWidth',
  'top',
  'bottom',
  'minHeight',
  'maxHeight',
  'lineHeight',
];

const PROPERTIES_DEPENDING_ON_NEITHER = [
  'fontSize',
  'margin',
  'padding',
  'borderWidth',
  'borderRadius',
  'borderTopLeftRadius',
  'borderTopRightRadius',
  'borderBottomLeftRadius',
  'borderBottomRightRadius',
];

const BASE_WIDTH = 375; // based on iPhone 6-8 width
const BASE_HEIGHT = 667; // based on iPhone 6-8 height

class StylingHelper {
  static setGuidelineBaseDimensions(
    guidelineBaseWidth = BASE_WIDTH,
    guidelineBaseHeight = BASE_HEIGHT,
  ) {
    const scalingFactor = 1;
    const horizontalFactor = (width / guidelineBaseWidth) * scalingFactor;
    const verticalFactor = (height / guidelineBaseHeight) * scalingFactor;
    const adimensionalFactor = (horizontalFactor + verticalFactor) / 2;

    PROPERTIES_DEPENDING_ON_WIDTH.forEach(key => {
      StyleSheet.setStyleAttributePreprocessor(key, value => {
        if (typeof value === 'number') {
          return PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(value * horizontalFactor);
        }

        return value;
      });
    });

    PROPERTIES_DEPENDING_ON_HEIGHT.forEach(key => {
      StyleSheet.setStyleAttributePreprocessor(key, value => {
        if (typeof value === 'number') {
          return PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(value * verticalFactor);
        }

        return value;
      });
    });

    PROPERTIES_DEPENDING_ON_NEITHER.forEach(key => {
      StyleSheet.setStyleAttributePreprocessor(key, value => {
        if (typeof value === 'number') {
          return PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(value * adimensionalFactor);
        }

        return value;
      });
    });
  }
}

export default StylingHelper;
```

Example Usage:

```js
// App.ts or index.js

//..

StylingHelper.setGuidelineBaseDimensions(390, 1024);
```